# Find key in array is not finding the text while it is there

Tags: php, arrays

I have an large array. I need to find the needle of a specific text.

Therefore I use:

```
$afmeting = array_search('extmax', $lines);
```

When I echo `$afmeting`  there is nothing there. But when I use `print_r` on the array I see it is there (needle 41). So what might be wrong?

```
Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => section [2] => 2 [3] => header [4] => 9 [5] => acadver [6] => 1 [7] => ac1027 [8] => 9 [9] => acadmaintver [10] => 70 [11] => 105 [12] => 9 [13] => dwgcodepage [14] => 3 [15] => ansi_1252 [16] => 9 [17] => requiredversions [18] => 160 [19] => 0 [20] => 9 [21] => lastsavedby [22] => 1 [23] => user [24] => 9 [25] => insbase [26] => 10 [27] => 0 [28] => 20 [29] => 0 [30] => 30 [31] => 0 [32] => 9 [33] => extmin [34] => 10 [35] => 0 [36] => 20 [37] => 0 [38] => 30 [39] => 0 [40] => 9 [41] => extmax [42] => 10 [43] => 260 [44] => 20 [45] => 150 [46] => 30 [47] => 0 [48] => 9 [49] => limmin [50] => 10 [51] => -26 [52] => 20 [53] => -15 [54] => 9 [55] => limmax [56] => 10 [57] => 286 [58] => 20 [59] => 165 [60] => 9 [61] => orthomode [62] => 70 [63] => 0 [64] => 9 [65] => regenmode [66] => 70 [67] => 1 [68] => 9 [69] => fillmode [70] => 70 [71] => 1 [72] => 9 [73] => qtextmode [74] => 70 [75] => 0 [76] => 9 [77] => mirrtext [78] => 70 [79] => 1 [80] => 9 [81] => ltscale [82] => 40 [83] => 1 [84] => 9 [85] => attmode [86] => 70 [87] => 1 [88] => 9 [89] => textsize [90] => 40 [91] => 0.2 [92] => 9 [93] => tracewid [94] => 40 [95] => 05 [96] => 9)
```

`print_r` gives: `[41] => extmax`

`var_dump` gives: `[41]=> string(8) "extmax "`

**EDIT after alle tips and tricks:**

Thank you all for contributing, so when I use this code all should be ok?

```
$afmeting = array_search('string(8) "extmax "', $lines, true);
```

But still no value when I echo `$afmeting`.

Comment: Please copy and paste the array. Don't attach images as we can't use them

Comment: Use `var_dump` to see more information of your array, `print_r` can be misleading.

Comment: @Muiter, a lesson for the future, try to paste the output of the array in one row using *echo "<pre>" just before the statement. It's not really helpful to read a extensively big array in one line like that.

Comment: The *needle* is generally the term used for the subject to search (`'extmax'`). The `41` thing here, is generally called the *key*.

Comment: So two problems perhaps: your value actually *isn't* `"extmax"` but `"extmax "` (in fact, `string(8) "extmax "` says there's one other hidden character in there for a total of `8` characters), and potentially it'll match the numbers first due to type juggling (see duplicate).

Comment: No, you're don't search for `'string(8) "extmax "'`. Your string isn't `'string(8) "extmax "'`. That is merely the debug output of `var_dump` telling you that the value is a `string` with `(8)` characters and the value `extmax `.

Comment: Thank you for explaing this @decese.
When I use `extmax` or `extmax ` I still see no result ?

Comment: Again, `var_dump` tells you that the string is 8 characters long, which obviously doesn't work for either "extmax" nor "extmax ". There's some other hidden character in there. Debug your string. Perhaps look at its raw bytes: `echo bin2hex($lines[41])`.

Answer (score 3):

```
$array=array(0=>'0',1=>'section',3=>'header',4=>'extmax');

$afmeting = array_search('extmax', $array);

echo $afmeting;
```

The error is happening because of your "int" records in the array. If you mark all your array values as string, you will get your array key result. The above code will return you the array key 4. Instead if *0* was an int value it would not return the array key that your needle is located.

A solution to this is after you get your array you use `array_map` function to convert all your array field to string like below:

```
$array=array(0=>0,1=>'section',3=>'header',4=>'extmax');

$array = array_map('strval', $array);

$afmeting = array_search('extmax', $array);

echo $afmeting;
```

This will provide you with the right key.

**Edit**

Another solution is to use parameter $strict of array_search and set it to `true`

```
$array=array(0=>0,1=>'section',3=>'header',4=>'extmax');

$afmeting = array_search('extmax', $array, true);

echo $afmeting;
```

This will also provide you with the right array key.

More about `array_search` function you can find [here!!!](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php)

Comment: The much easier solution is to use `$strict` search mode.

Comment: You are right. I will also add it as a third improved solution. Thanks for mentioning

Comment: PHP doesn't have named arguments. `$strict=true` is nonsense and/or doesn't do what you think it does. Just do `array_search('extmax', $array, true)`.

Comment: Didn't know that i was always using strict parameter like this. Edited my answer and will look further into this. Until now everytime i used it like $strict=true it worked fine for me but if you mention that it's wrong i will investigate on that. Thanks for pointing out.